# Make live/active wallpaper with Flash CS6 and as3 for android?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, wallpaper

I have been trying to figure out this for a long time, I know most of pages out there and even threads here tell to do that through Java and the android SDK, but I wonder if there is any actual way to make them the same way we can make regular APK for games etc using only as3 and Flash pro.
Any help or clue I would greatly appreciate, thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do it with AIR. You could possibly do it via an AIR Native Extension, but it seems unlikely, and most of the app would still end up being written in Java, I think.

AIR isn't meant to be a replacement for native apps. It's meant to be a simple way to build cross-platform apps. Things like live wallpapers, custom keyboards, launchers, etc. are well outside the realm of the AIR project.

Comment: Thanks a lot I was totally lost on that, I will try through the android sdk and java then. As said thanks a lot